# Определение цвета по RGB | python

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект

У нас есть дата-сет, в котором есть  значения RGB.Например,

> 175 91 53

И лэйбл - красный.Какие можно вытащить из этого фичи? или как-то определять цвет? Вот ссылка на пример выше(P.S цвет не похож на красный, но считаем красным):

https://convertingcolors.com/rgb-color-175_91_53.html

Comment: нужно что-то типа 175 > 91 + 53 = цвет красный?и так для каждого цвета проверку делать?

Comment: 207, 147, 108 - тоже красный, но сумма больше R

Comment: дайте определение красного цвета ;)

Comment: Дата-сет как-то криво составлся.blue,
green,yellow,
red,
white,
orange.Возможно, тут стоит считать, на что больше похоже.Или просто knn какой-нибудь заюзать.

Comment: Может - поможет.
https://www.r-bloggers.com/utilizing-k-means-to-extract-colours-from-your-favourite-images/
"Utilizing K-means to extract colours from your favourite images"

Answer (score 2):

Переведите цвет из RGB представления в модель [HSV](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_(%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C)) и соотнесите значение оттенка с названием цвета (нужно будет задать диапазоны).

При малой насыщенности цвет будет серым (белым, черным - в зависимости от яркости)